# There is this place

Tags: american-english, british-english, informal-language, existentials

I have been reading the novel *Bad for You* for the last ten days. I have read a small sentence and in the small sentence a small phrase did not sound natural to my ears. So I landed here to get some help on it.

> Bad for You
>
> I shook my head as I stared at him, confused. Krit didn’t get up at
>   ten ever. He partied all night and slept most of the day.
>
> “Good. **There’s this** place I know that has incredible pancakes, and I
>   want some pancakes,” he said then nodded toward the stairs leading
>   down to the parking lot. “Come on. Eat breakfast with me.”

My question is that does it (**There’s this place**) sound natural? I think it could be (**there is a** place, **there is the** place but **there is this** place does not sound natural or maybe not good) one of them.  Maybe it is grammatically right or also making sense but not to me (a non-native English speaker) at the moment. Because *there* **shows that something is away from us** and *this* shows **something is nearby us**. So using *there* and *this* together not sounding right to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You correctly understand that this use of *this* is not Standard, and is not employed in formal discourse; and I agree with you that the demonstrative pronoun jars in this context, whether you understand *there* as a dummy pronoun or a demonstrative pro-adverb.

The fact is that *this* is used here not as a demonstrative but as a sort of article with something of the senses of both *the* and *a*. You might think of it as an ‘introductory definite’ article: speakers say *this NOUN* when they have a specific instance of *NOUN* in mind which has not yet been introduced into the discourse.

> I know this guy who can fix that for you cheap.

He’s not a guy who’s actually present and I’m pointing to, but he’s not just any guy, either, he’s not just one of several guys I know who can fix things, he’s a very particular guy whose services I’m recommending.

This is a very common colloquial use, and it is ‘non-Standard’ rather than ‘sub-Standard’: you might very well hear English professors use it in conversation:

> There’s this paper I saw a couple of years ago, might have been in Shakespeare Quarterly or TDR?, addressed exactly the question you’re asking.

Answer (score 5):

You example "There's this place" expands to:

> There is this place.

In this case, *there* isn't describing the location of something - it's a dummy subject, that doesn't mean anything, and it's used because English requires it when you're saying that something exists.

You can test it by asking *where* the *thing* is. If you can ask (and answer) the question (and it's sensible), then *there* refers to a place. Otherwise, it's just part of an existential clause.

For instance, as a minimal pair.

- There is a chance it will rain tomorrow.

  - Where is a chance it will rain tomorrow?
    *You can't ask this question in English. The chance doesn't have a location.*
- There is a dog.

  - Where is a dog?
    There! *points*

    - There's a slight problem with this one: English speakers are far more likely to say *Where is there a dog?*, and in that case, the *there* is a dummy subject. **However, this question still works.**

The short answer to your question: in this case **there** doesn't describe the distance from "this place". Additionally, **this** probably doesn't describe how close the "place" is, either - it's just colloquial talk, and is used in place of *a* (non-specific, indeterminate article).

You can *definitely* use *there* and *this* in close proximity.

The case above, where "there" carries no meaning, as well as when there's news in the sentence somewhere.

For instance, *this place exists there*, it is difficult to read this without emphasis on "this", "exists", or "there".

- *This* place exists there: this place, and not some other place, exists there.
- This place *exists* there: this place exists there, even if it doesn't exist here.
- This place exists *there*: this place exists over there, even if it doesn't here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It was helpful. But "there" and "this" do not make sense together. My question is that should I avoid them together?

Comment: @user62015 In these examples, **there** does not describe something that is distal. It is used because English requires a subject, and in other languages, you could just say "exists this place". You can definitely use them together, as long as it is used in a similar way to the first example I gave - "there is a chance it will rain tomorrow". (I've added a bit more detail to the examples to try to make things clearer.)

Comment: @jimsug "this place exists that...". Honestly though, I'm a native speaker and this sounds very natural to me(I say it all the time) but I think OP has a point. I get that "there" is semantically null, but "this" isn't. If you're simply asserting the existence of a place, why not use "a"? "This" sounds like you're talking about where you are now, in which case "this place exists" is trivial, and not the intent of the statement.

Comment: @Cruncher precisely my point. You wouldn't say "this place exists" if you were talking about your current location. "This", then, stands for "a" - I can't remember the exact distinction, if there is one. Also: "This place exists" works. "This place exists that"? I'm not sure about this one. Did you mean "This place exists _there_"? This also works fine.

Comment: @jimsug no I mean "this place exists that [properties of the place]" it was in response to your "exists this place" as an alternative.